# while creating a react app I am getting an error as "npm ERR! code 1 npm ERR! node-sass npm ERR! command failed"

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, npx

I am trying to create an app in react node but
I am getting an error help me with it

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\Programs\btech\virtual experence\backpack\my-app\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\Programs\btech\virtual experence\backpack\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\\Programs\\btech\\virtual experence\\backpack\\my-app\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.10.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python" can be used
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executable path is
```

[![error img][1]][1]

I have also attached a screenshot of it my npm version is 9.2.0 and the node version is v18.10.0
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TirZi.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue and just uninstalled the node-sass
`npm uninstall node-sass`

Then I installed sass as a devDependency
`npm install sass --save-dev`